# Why my symbols been cleared?

Tags: memory, machine-learning

I have about 60000 data to train.
After minutes of calculation,all symbols are cleared.
Is it a Bug?
I have 8G memories ,but it's not enough.My cpu is i5-4590. 
Here are my codes:

```
data=ExampleData[{"MachineLearning","MNIST"},"TestData"];
trainingdata=RandomChoice[data,3000];
testdata=RandomChoice[data,1000];
maketuple[i_]=Array[If[i+1==#,1,0]&,10];
transformdata[d_]:=Module[{data=d[[;;,1]],label=d[[;;,2]]},
Flatten[Table[Append[maketuple[j],data[[i]]]->label[[i]]==j,{i,1,Length[data]},{j,0,9}],1]];
tdata=transformdata[trainingdata];
ttest=transformdata[testdata];
c=Classify[tdata];
ClassifierMeasurements[c,ttest,"Accuracy"]
```

Problem happen when calculate `c=Classify[tdata]`.
If I use `c=Classify[tdata,Method->"LogisticRegression"];` everything is ok.

Actually I need to add some information to train.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until someone else has confirmed your observations. In the meantime: it does seem as if your computer is not sufficiently powerful for 60,000; would a smaller number suffice?

Comment: can you reproduce this all the time? Are you sure you are not calling ClearAll[...] or Clear[`Global*`] any where? or may be the Kernel crashed? That will also cause variable to be cleared.

Comment: @J.M. I don't know what tag should be.it should not lose all symbols without any information . I can wait but it seems something go wrong. I will add more information later

Comment: When you found your vars are cleared, observe the `In` `Out` label. If they start from one, than your kernel is crashed.

Comment: @happyfish you can right.what is the problem

Comment: @Nasser what should I do to deal with crash

Comment: @erow I found this problem interesting. The kernel even crashes with 40 training data, while the memory usage never exceed 1GB. I am confused by your way of converting the training data. Usually people train __multiple classifiers__ (OvR) if they want to translate a multi class classification to a binary one. You are basically adding the target information into features and gives true when they match. This makes you have `sample*class` training data. And you are prepending one hot version of class, which significantly increases the number of features.

Comment: @happyfish yeah. I think it's a wonderful idea.now I need mathematica to prove my idea. I really think there are a bug to let it crash

Comment: @erow I implemented your idea with python, I got worse accuracy and longer training time.  Nevertheless, this is off topic on this site.

Comment: @happyfish In fact,it does not work well.I train other data using LogisticRegression and it is truely worse.But become better when use NeuralNetwork.I think need more test.And the vector form `{img, {1,0,0..}}->True|False`  is better than `{img, #}->True|False`

Comment: @erow you are right. The size of onehot vector is negligible compared to the image, I should retract my second remark. and formulating classes as numbers introduces some unintended information, which is expected to have problems especially for nn

Comment: @happyfish Can you give me a Contact information？When I randomchoice 10000 data,it performs well.I think it need more study.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56108/discussion-between-happy-fish-and-erow).

Comment: @J.M it crashed for some situations.I really need mathematica to train a large data.If mathematica can not do this,i have to give up.